# Kafka Security implementation issue SASL SSL and SCRAM

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, sasl-scram

I'm facing error while starting kafka server,
have setup the SSL and it's working fine for kafka 3 brokers. And zookeeper is also setup with SSL

Now tried to setup the SCRAM with SASL_SSL for kafka broker from server property file.

It's not working I have created a user with following command

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2182 --zk-tls-config-file zookeeper-client.properties --entity-type users --entity-name broker-admin --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=DEM123]'
```

and I can see user is created.

but while trying to run the command to run kafka broker

```
kafka-server-start.sh -daemon server-0.properties
```

It is having some error while I have checked server.log file

```
[2021-10-05 16:21:38,369] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /config/users/broker-admin

Can anyone support me?

let me share my zookeeper.proerpties file

```
dataDir=/var/www/kafka/data/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
secureClientPort=2182
authProvider.x509=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.X509AuthenticationProvider
serverCnxnFactory=org.apache.zookeeper.server.NettyServerCnxnFactory
ssl.trustStore.location=/var/www/kafka/ssl/kafka.zookeeper.truststore.jks
ssl.trustStore.password=zookeepbook
ssl.keyStore.location=/var/www/kafka/ssl/kafka.zookeeper.keystore.jks
ssl.keyStore.password=zookeepbook
ssl.clientAuth=need
maxClientCnxns=0
admin.enableServer=true
admin.serverPort=9090
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
```

server.properties file content :

```
broker.id=0
listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2182
log.dirs=/var/www/kafka/data/broker-0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0


zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket=org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty
zookeeper.ssl.client.enable=true
zookeeper.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location=/var/www/kafka/ssl/kafka.broker-0.truststore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password=zookeepbookbrk0
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location=/var/www/kafka/ssl/kafka.broker-0.keystore.jks
zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password=zookeepbookbrk0

zookeeper.set.acl=true


ssl.truststore.location=/var/www/kafka/ssl/kafka.broker-0.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=zookeepbookbrk0
ssl.keystore.location=/var/www/kafka/ssl/kafka.broker-0.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=zookeepbookbrk0
ssl.key.password=zookeepbookbrk0
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.client.auth=none
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-512
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-512.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='broker-admin' password=DEM123;
super.users=User:broker-admin
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to set 'skipACL=yes' to your zookeeper.properties ?
If you authenticated with Zookeeper by using SSL client certs when you created 'broker-admin' user, I think it because access from other than the place where you executed the command is denied.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. Fixed it now.

I faced this issue because, I have setup Kafka and ZK with some certain user credentials, later I changed it, so I am getting this error

> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode
> = NoAuth for /config/users/old-user-name

So, restarting Kafka Server should ideally fix the issue.

If this did not work, try restarting the whole machine.(If this worked, you did not restart the Kafka Server properly before).